# want to create excel file using python by preserving all the rows and columns in text format

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to create an excel file using pandas, but the cells remains in general format, whereas I want all the data to be in formatted text.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1, sep='|', dtype=str,  encoding='utf-8')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(refile1, engine='xlsxwriter', options={'encoding':'utf-8'})
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Attendee List', startrow=3, startcol=1, index=False, header=True, encoding='utf-8',)
workbook  = writer.book
```

Comment: When you say "general format", do you mean you're getting the default Calibre, font size 12 format? What format are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

I found this site on adding formatting to excel columns:
http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html

Basically, you need to define some formats like so:

```
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})
```

and then assign the formats to certain columns like so:

```
worksheet.set_column('B:B', 18, format1)
worksheet.set_column('C:C', None, format2)
```